# How to delete last n commits of a branch from git after I have pushed?

Tags: git, github

I want to delete the last 10 commits(and pushed too) I have done in my repo

Past I have tried this

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

But I think this will delete all the commits . How to just delete the last n commits from the git completely after I have pushed it .. ?

Comment: Working alone on this repo?

Comment: No two members are there but he have not pulled it yet

Comment: Have seen it but still confuse HOW TO DELETE N NUMBERS OF COMMIT

Comment: What is your confusion ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you don't try to delete them but instead `git revert` them. You will then create a new commit which removes the content of those few commits, and the operation will remain visible in the history (helping everyone understand what's going on).

```
$ git revert --no-commit HEAD^
$ git revert --no-commit HEAD^^
$ git revert --no-commit HEAD^^^
...
$ git commit -m "revert last ten commits"
```

Comment: Yes, this is good practice. Maybe consider the short syntax variant `git revert -n HEAD~10..` to revert the ten last. Or preferably log your last commits, store the hash of the last "good commit", and do `git revert -n <goodCommitHash>..` (mind the two dots at the end, this is the syntax to imply a range between something and `HEAD`). Don't forget to `add` any conflict resolutions, and commit at the end.